# Add refernce and call a winform project from another project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm having 2 projects: 
P1: Winform project and
P2: Class Library project.
I want call a method of P1 from P2, so I do:

1. Right click to P2
2. Choose Add Reference
3. Choose project P1

Then in P2, I add

```
using P1;
```

and declare class MyP1Class of P1 in P2

```
public P1.MyP1Class p1class;
```

VisualStudio responses the message:

> Error 1   Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'P1' does not have a strong name

Hope someone can help me, any help is appreciate, thanks.

Comment: Clearly you gave P2 a strong name.  Which requires that P1 has a strong name as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `Strong-Named Assemblies` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx).

This is [How to: Sign an Assembly with a Strong Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx).